# Laravel 5.4: return response json groupBy created_at

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5.4

I have this controller which group the Collection by date

```
public function index() {
        $poLists = ( new PurchaseOrder() )
            ->where( 'needed_quantity', '>', 0 )
            ->where( 'supplier_id', $this->guard()->user()->id )
            ->get()->groupBy( function ( $item ) {
                return [ $item->created_at->format( 'Y-m-d HH:mm:ss' ) ];
            } );

        return response()->json( $poLists, 200 );
    }
```

working fine and this is the output

```
{
    "2019-02-18 1212:0202:3939": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2019-02-18 12:16:39",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-18 12:16:39"
        }
    ],
    "2019-02-18 1515:0202:0202": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "created_at": "2019-02-18 15:21:02",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-18 15:21:02"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "created_at": "2019-02-18 15:21:02",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-18 15:21:02"
        }
    ],
```

is there is a way to add static key for each group like

```
{
    date: "2019-02-18 1212:0202:3939" [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2019-02-18 12:16:39",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-18 12:16:39"
        }
    ],
    date: "2019-02-18 1515:0202:0202": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "barcode": 33254,
            "status": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-02-18 15:21:02",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-18 15:21:02"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "created_at": "2019-02-18 15:21:02",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-18 15:21:02"
        }
    ],
```

Here is `date` is the static key

Comment: Can you explain what you trying to achieve? What do you want to do with this "static key"?

Comment: @Daniel it's all about the Android client developer he needs the key to catch the groups by the key

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `$poList` results data with array with desired key:

```
$results = [
    'date' => $poLists
];
return response()->json($results, 200);
```

Now, in `$results['date']` have all data grouped by date:

```
{
    "date": [
        "2019-02-18 1212:0202:3939" [
            {
               "id": 2,
                "created_at": "2019-02-18 12:16:39",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-18 12:16:39"
            }
        ],
        "2019-02-18 1515:0202:0202": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "barcode": 33254,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2019-02-18 15:21:02",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-18 15:21:02"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "created_at": "2019-02-18 15:21:02",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-18 15:21:02"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi thanks but still this not what I am looking for I need this `date` to be a key for each group something like this `date: "2019-02-18 1212:0202:3939"`

Comment: What valid JSON output you expect?